# In pandas, how can all columns that do not contain at least one NaN be dropped from a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a DataFrame in which some columns have `NaN` values. I want to drop all columns that do not have at least one `NaN` value in them.

I am able to identify the `NaN` values by creating a DataFrame filled with Boolean values (`True` in place of `NaN` values, `False` otherwise):

```
data.isnull()
```

Then, I am able to identify the columns that contain at least one `NaN` value by creating a series of column names with associated Boolean values (`True` if the column contains at least one `NaN` value, `False` otherwise):

```
data.isnull().any(axis = 0)
```

When I attempt to use this series to drop the columns that do not contain at least one `NaN` value, I run into a problem: the columns that do not contain `NaN` values are dropped:

```
data = data.loc[:, data.isnull().any(axis = 0)]
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2, None],
        [3, None, 4],
        [5, 6, None]
    ], columns=list('ABC'))

df

   A    B    C
0  1  2.0  NaN
1  3  NaN  4.0
2  5  6.0  NaN
```

IIUC:

***`pandas`***
*`dropna` with `thresh` parameter*

```
df.dropna(1, thresh=2)

   A    B
0  1  2.0
1  3  NaN
2  5  6.0
```

*`loc` + boolean indexing*

```
df.loc[:, df.isnull().sum() < 2]

   A    B
0  1  2.0
1  3  NaN
2  5  6.0
```

Comment: I'm confused.  The OP said "I want to drop all columns that do not have at least one NaN value in them".  Your column A does not have at least one NaN value, and so I think he wants to drop it.  What am I missing?

Comment: @DSM me too, hence the "IIUC".  However, notice that they say "When I attempt to use this series to drop the columns that do not contain at least one NaN value, I run into a problem: the columns that do not contain NaN values are dropped:"... Meaning they ran exactly what I would've run after interpreting their language description and after they did, they got the results I thought they were after.  So I'm left assuming they meant something else.  What I provided is what I'm guessing they meant.  That is no more than one NaN.

Comment: You could very well be right, although if so the OP chose some an oddly specific way to be wrong. :-)   I guess we'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

I used sample DF from @piRSquared's answer.

If you want to `"to drop the columns that do not contain at least one NaN value"`:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   A    B    C
0  1  2.0  NaN
1  3  NaN  4.0
2  5  6.0  NaN

In [26]: df.loc[:, df.isnull().any()]
Out[26]:
     B    C
0  2.0  NaN
1  NaN  4.0
2  6.0  NaN
```